# How to change input command with button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.9

I'm making a virtual assistant and I'm designing the interface for it. In line number 219-220 I want the input command to be replaced by a button in Tkinter but it fails when I log in, the virtual assistant greets me and doesn't show up on the interface screen and keeps saying "you:" "Jarvis:". I need your help thanks

Here is my code

```
#import modules

from tkinter import *
import os
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
import pyjokes
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import requests
import smtplib
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser as we
from datetime import date
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
import random
import os
import wikipedia
from typing import Text
import time
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys
import subprocess

# Designing window for registration


def register():
    def exit():
        register_screen.destroy()

    global register_screen
    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Sign in")
    register_screen.geometry("400x350")
    register_screen.configure(bg='#80ffff')

    global username
    global password
    global name
    global name_entry
    global dob
    global dob_entry
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    name = StringVar()
    dob = StringVar()

    sign_in = Label(register_screen, text="Sign in", bg="#ff8533",
                    width="40", height="2", font=("Calibri", 15))
    sign_in.place(x=0, y=0)

    username_lable = Label(register_screen, height=2,
                           text="Username *", font="25", bg="#ff80ff", width="15")
    username_lable.place(x=20, y=70)

    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, width=30,
                           fg="#5c5c3d", textvariable=username)
    username_entry.place(x=170, y=83)

    password_lable = Label(register_screen, height=2,
                           text="Password * ", font="25", bg="#ffff33", width="15")
    password_lable.place(x=20, y=120)

    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, width=30,
                           fg="#5c5c3d", textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.place(x=170, y=133)

    name_lable = Label(register_screen, height=2,
                       text="Enter your name", font="25", bg="#ff3333", width="15")
    name_lable.place(x=20, y=170)

    name_entry = Entry(register_screen, width=30,
                       fg="#5c5c3d", textvariable=name)
    name_entry.place(x=170, y=183)

    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    exitButton = Button(register_screen, text="Exit", bg="red",
                        fg="white", width=4, font=7, command=exit).place(x=190, y=230)
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=8, bg="#00ff00",
           font=7, command=register_user).place(x=270, y=230)


# Designing window for login

def login():
    def exit2():
        login_screen.destroy()

    global login_screen
    login_screen = Tk
    login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.configure(bg='#ffb3b3')
    login_screen.geometry("400x350")
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login",
          bg="#d966ff", font="30", width=300, height=3).pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    Label(login_screen, text="Username * ", font="25",
          bg="#80dfff", height=2).place(x=20, y=70)

    username_login_entry = Entry(
        login_screen, width=30, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.place(x=150, y=83)

    Label(login_screen, text="Password * ", font="25",
          bg="#1aff1a", height=2).place(x=20, y=120)

    password_login_entry = Entry(
        login_screen, width=30, textvariable=password_verify, show='*')
    password_login_entry.place(x=150, y=133)

    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1,
           bg="#ff471a", command=login_verify).place(x=252, y=183)

    Button(login_screen, text="Exit", bg="#ffff4d", width=6,
           height=1, command=exit2).place(x=180, y=183)
    login_screen.mainloop()

# Implementing event on register button


def register_user():

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    name_info = name.get()

    file = open(username_info, "w")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info + "\n")
    file.write(name_info + "\n")
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)
    name_entry.delete(0, END)

    register_screen.destroy()
# Implementing event on login button


def login_verify():
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            Jarvis_assistant()

        else:
            password_not_recognised()

    else:
        user_not_found()

# Designing popup for login success


def Jarvis_assistant():

    global login_success_screen
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("Success")
    login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()

    user = "Mr.Stark"  # your name
    assistant = "Jarvis"  # Iron man Fan

    Jarvis_mouth = pyttsx3.init()
    Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("rate", 165)
    voices = Jarvis_mouth.getProperty("voices")

    # For Mail voice AKA Jarvis
    Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)

    def Jarvis_brain(audio):
        robot = Jarvis_brain
        print("Jarvis: " + audio)
        Jarvis_mouth.say(audio)
        Jarvis_mouth.runAndWait()

    #Jarvis speech
    #Jarvis_ear = listener
    #Jarvis_brain = speak
    #Jarvis_mouth = engine
    #you = command

    def inputCommand():
        # you = input() # For getting input from CLI
        Jarvis_ear = sr.Recognizer()
        you = ""
        with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as mic:
            Jarvis_ear.pause_threshold = 1
            try:
                Button(login_screen, text="Press to listen...", bg="#ffff4d", width=6,
                        height=1, command=inputCommand).place(x=0, y=50)
                #input("Press to listen...") instead of using input I want to change this in to a button on tkinter
                print("Listening...")
                you = Jarvis_ear.recognize_google(
                    Jarvis_ear.listen(mic), language="en-IN")
            except Exception as e:
                Jarvis_brain(" ")
            except:
                you = ""
            print("You: " + you)

        return you

    def greet():
        hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
        if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
            main_screen.destroy()
            Jarvis_brain(f"Hello, Good Morning {user}")
            print("Hello,Good Morning")
        elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
            main_screen.destroy()
            Jarvis_brain(f"Hello, Good Afternoon {user}")
            print("Hello, Good Afternoon")
        else:
            main_screen.destroy()
            Jarvis_brain(f"Hello, Good Evening {user}")
            print("Hello,Good Evening")
    greet()

    def main():
        while True:
            # Getting input from the user
            you = inputCommand().lower()
            #General question.
            if ("hello" in you) or ("Hi" in you):
                Jarvis_brain(random.choice(
                    ["how may i help you, sir.", "Hi,sir"]))

            elif ("time" in you):
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                robot_brain = now.strftime("%H hour %M minutes %S seconds")
                Jarvis_brain(robot_brain)

            elif ("date" in you):
                today = date.today()
                robot_brain = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
                Jarvis_brain(robot_brain)

            elif ("joke" in you):
                Jarvis_brain(pyjokes.get_joke())

            elif "president of America" in you:
                Jarvis_brain("Donald Trump")

            #open application
            elif ("play" in you):
                song = you.replace('play', '')
                Jarvis_brain('playing ' + song)
                pywhatkit.playonyt(song)

            elif ("open youtube" in you):
                Jarvis_brain("opening YouTube")
                we.open('https://www.youtube.com/')

            elif ("open google" in you):
                Jarvis_brain("opening google")
                we.open('https://www.google.com/')

            elif "information" in you:
                you = you.replace("find imformation", "")
                Jarvis_brain("what news you what to know about")
                topic = inputCommand()
                Jarvis_brain("open " + topic)
                we.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + topic)

            elif ("open gmail" in you):
                Jarvis_brain("opening gmail")
                we.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2/#inbox')

            elif "vietnamese translate" in you:
                Jarvis_brain("opening Vietnamese Translate")
                we.open('https://translate.google.com/?hl=vi')

            elif "english translate" in you:
                Jarvis_brain("opening English Translate")
                we.open(
                    'https://translate.google.com/?hl=vi&sl=en&tl=vi&op=translate')

            elif ("open internet") in you:
                Jarvis_brain("opening internet")
                openInternet = "C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\Brave.exe"
                os.startfile(openInternet)

            elif "wikipedia" in you:
                you = you.replace("wikipedia", "")
                Jarvis_brain("what topic you need to listen to")
                topic = inputCommand()
                results = wikipedia.summary(
                    topic, auto_suggest=False, redirect=True)
                print(results)
                Jarvis_brain(results)

        #New&Covid-19

            elif ("covid-19" in you):
                r = requests.get(
                    'https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/all').json()
                Jarvis_brain(
                    f'Confirmed Cases: {r["cases"]} \nDeaths: {r["deaths"]} \nRecovered {r["recovered"]}')

            else:
                if "bye" in you:
                    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
                    if (hour >= 21) and (hour < 5):
                        Jarvis_brain(f"Good Night {user}! Have a nice Sleep")
                        exit()
                    else:
                        Jarvis_brain(f"Bye {user}")
                        exit()

    main()


# Designing popup for login invalid password
def delete_password_not_recognised():
    password_not_recog_screen.destroy()


def delete_user_not_found_screen():
    user_not_found_screen.destroy()


def password_not_recognised():
    global password_not_recog_screen
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Fail to login")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("250x150")
    password_not_recog_screen.configure(bg='#66ffff')
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ", font="30",bg="#ff99cc", width="30").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="Exit", bg="red", fg="white",
           width=5, command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()

# Designing popup for user not found


def user_not_found():
    global user_not_found_screen
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Fail to login")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("250x150")
    user_not_found_screen.configure(bg='#66ffff')
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found",bg="#ff99cc", width="30", font="30").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="Exit", bg="red", fg="white",
           width=5, command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()


# Designing Main(first) window

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("500x350")
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    main_screen.configure(bg='#ffcccc')
    Label(text="Sign in and Login in", bg="#00ffff", width="50",
          height="2", font=("Calibri", 15)).place(x=0, y=0)
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30",
           command=login, bg="#1aff1a").place(x=140, y=80)
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30",
           command=register, bg="#ff1a1a").place(x=140, y=150)
    main_screen.mainloop()


main_account_screen()
```

And here is my terminal

```
    PS C:\Users\PC> & C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/PC/Desktop/lamdoan/loginform.py
Jarvis: Hello, Good Evening Mr.Stark
Hello,Good Evening
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You: 
Jarvis:  
You:
```

Comment: provide a [mre] (emphasis on _minimal_ (that is like 50 lines of code MAX)), based on your title only it seems you are looking for `.config` method for configuring widgets

Comment: does the script check for a working mic before starting ?

Comment: what main() just after def main(): block does ?

Comment: don't create that many nested functions, use classes instead or don't nest functions